# What is a prefix that means near?

Tags: prefixes

For instance, if I were to describe someone as being **near-**carnivorous, I'm have the goal of depicting them as being a heavy meat eater that includes very few forms of non-meat based food in their diet as opposed to being one who exclusively consumes meat.

Comment: You would have to use an adverb like *largely* or *mostly* — or *near*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm very much in favour of *quasi-* for this purpose, but *near* serves the purpose, as does *mostly*.

> Quasi- used to show that something is almost, but not completely, the thing described
>   http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/quasi?q=quasi

Comment: Yes, but in some contexts I quite like the "suffix" **XXX manqué** for someone/something that doesn't quite make the grade as an XXX.

Comment: Perhaps, but quasi is often used negatively in my experience. If the intent is to show that quasicarnivorous is not as good as carnivorous then this works. I think semi is more neutral but certainly does not indicate 'mostly'.

Answer (score 4):

The prefix *[peri-](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/peri-)* may suit

> enclosing, encircling, or around ⇒ pericardium, pericarp, perigon
>   near or adjacent ⇒ perihelion

Comment: peri is more physical location than state of being. Peri is largely used in the medical field because it is a prefix to describe location.

Answer (score 4):

> "semi: a Latin prefix to a verb, noun, or adjective meaning 'half'".

Even though it means half, it is often used in context to mean "**almost**", especially in cases when it is applied to non-measurable concepts. Some examples are "semi-automatic firearm", "semi-parasitic creature", or "semi-arid climate".

I think that "pseudo-" could work in the context of "near carnivorous". Pseudo means "false" or "mock", so it would not work in all cases as "near". But "pseudo-carnivorous" for some reason sounds more natural to me than "semi-carnivorous".

Answer (score 2):

I think *para-* comes closest, when used in the sense of *resembling* or *similar*, as in *para-military*, *para-medic* or *para-legal*.

Others you might consider in particular contexts are *quasi-* and *crypto-*.

Comment: There are too many other senses of [para-](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/para-) for this to be of much use. Also, the *para* in *paralegal* means subsidiary to, not "nearly" a lawyer.

Comment: @Robusto I disagree with your first point; the first time I heard the term paramedic, I understood what it must mean based on my understanding of paramilitary and so on.  It was clear that the other meanings were inappropriate.  I also contest your second point; *paralegal* may mean a person assisting a lawyer, but the *para-* in *paralegal* does **not** mean subsidiary to; it is using the meaning of *para-* as "near or alongside", because the paralegal is an *auxilliary*. *para-* does not have a meaning of "subsidiary to".

Answer (score 2):

According to Wikipedia, English has borrowed *presque-isle* from the French, to mean a peninsula with an unusually narrow neck. However, this seems to be the sole use of this prefix in English - so far.

*Carnivorous* is essentially a non-gradable (because it classifies) adjective. To get round this fact to describe an animal eating say 98% meat, one could use the construction 'almost exclusively carnivorous'.

Answer (score 0):

While not a prefix, your instance appears to perfectly describe [obligate carnivores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnivore#Obligate_carnivores).

Besides *quasi* (which I like), you can also consider the prefix [cis-](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cis-) which is *from Latin cis 'on this side of'*.

Answer (score 0):

Why not pen-, as in penultimate or peninsula?

Comment: I do not believe *pen-* to be a productive prefix in English. *Penultimate* and *peninsula* were borrowed *in toto* from Latin.