# A prefix for to describe doing something in close distance

Tags: single-word-requests, prefixes

When we want to describe an action which is done over a (*physical*) far distance, we attach the prefix '*Tele*-' to the proper word related to that action: *TELE*vision, *TELE*phone, *TELE*graph etc.

I am looking for a prefix to describe an action which is done in a close distance. Is there any prefix in English or Latin that can be used for such a purpose?

In Persian language, we use the prefix 'Door /du:r/' equivalent to 'Tele': /du:rnega:'r/ = Telefax and we use prefix 'Ham /ham/' for describing any kind of close (in distance or in meaning or in function): /ham-ota:Gi/ = roommate, /ham-kela:si/ = classmate

Comment: There is NFC (near-field communications). But that's not what you're after, I think.

Comment: @NVZ First of all thanks for editing. I am looking for something that can be used generally just like 'Tele'

Comment: Is there a particular word for which you need the prefix?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87856/what-is-a-prefix-that-means-near

Comment: @JOSH If you read my question, you may found that it's talking about close in physical distance and not close in meaning or in function as mentioned in that question. So I don't think it's really a duplicate.

Comment: Seems like *proxi* should be such a prefix, but I don't really find any words with it (other than *proximal*, *proximo*, etc.).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The prefix ***[peri-](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/peri-)*** is used to suggest "close/near", not a common one. Though:

> - a prefix meaning “about” or “around” ( perimeter, periscope), “enclosing” or “surrounding” ( pericardium), ***and “near” ( perigee, perihelion),***  appearing in loanwords from Greek ( peripeteia); on this model, used in the formation of compound words ( perimorph).

Comment: This is a precise response, and deserves to be given "correct answer" status.

Comment: One note is that *peri-* is usually contrasted with *apo-* rather than *tele-* (consider perigee, apogee). However, *apo-* is much less common and productive than *tele-*.